# Measure accuracy of Holt-Winters model

Tags: r, time-series, accuracy

I'm really confused about measuring the accuracy of Holt-Winters fitted models applying different transformations.

How do i compare the accuracy between models when i apply no transformation to the data, the BoxCox power transformation and, for instance, log transformation?

Say i have a time series x.

```
fit1 <- HoltWinters(x)
f1 <- forecast.HoltWinters(fit1, h=12)
accuracy(f1)

fit2 <- HoltWinters(BoxCox(x))
f2 <- forecast.HoltWinters(fit2, h=12, lambda=BoxCox.lambda(x))
accuracy(f2)

fit3 <- HoltWinters(log(x))
f3 <- forecast.HoltWinters(fit3, h=12)
accuracy(f3)
```

The first 2, i think are comparable because i passed the parameter lambda to the forecast.HoltWinters() to the second one. But what about the other one? Do i apply the inverse if the natural logarithm like this

```
exp(accuracy(f3))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the scale on which you want to have accuracy, and convert your forecasts to that scale before evaluating the accuracy. Then you compare the various approaches on the same scale.

Exponentiating the accuracy is on the same thing as exponentiating the forecasts and then measuring the accuracy, though if 'accuracy' (I am not familiar with this function) is returning a measurement on the same scale as the data, the transformed accuracy could sometimes yield something close to the accuracy of the transformed forecasts.